# Snowflake Snowsight Marketplace: User's configured default role does not exist or not authorized

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to access Snowflake's marketplace (Trying to access Snowsight gives the same error message). when I log onto the legacy browser UI and click on "Data Marketplace", it takes me to the log in screen again. When I put in my credentials it gives me an error that says: `User's configured default role '<username>' does not exist or not authorized. Contact your local system administrator, or attempt to login using a CLI client with a connect string selecting another role, e.g. PUBLIC.`

My role has `accountadmin` level privileges so I'm not sure why this is appearing. To be thorough I granted myself `IMPORT SHARE` privileges directly to my role, but that didn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `DESC USER <username>;` and see what the default_role is set to. Most likely it's a mismatch on role that isn't assigned to that user. You can change the default role to something else by using the command:

`ALTER USER <usernmae> SET DEFAULT_ROLE = <rolename>;`

Comment: This was the most technically correct of the answers. The mismatch was a mismatch due to the case of the role name (my biggest beef with snowflake is this whole uppercase/lowercase nonsense). When I ran `DESC USER user_a` it gave me a default role of `user_a_role` when what it needed to be was `USER_A_ROLE`.

I've come to learn that this happens when you set a default role with quotes, like:
`ALTER USER user_a SET DEFAULT_ROLE = 'user_a_role';`
rather than:
`ALTER USER user_a SET DEFAULT_ROLE = user_a_role;`
which, rather unintuitively, makes the role name uppercase rather than lower.

Answer (score 0):

Snowsight will allow a user to log in with their DEFAULT_ROLE. You will receive this error when a user’s DEFAULT_ROLE is not granted to a user or the role was dropped or deleted.

To log in successfully, you should request an administrator to grant you the required role or you will have to set a different default_role for your user that you have access to, and then you will be able to log in.